# Java Android Bitmap references

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I am creating this Android project with Java. However, I am wondering a bit how far the references with some Bitmap methods will go.

I have an originally Bitmap just like:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, bitmapID);
```

and then I send it to an object within its constructor of a basic class:

```
class Test
{
    Bitmap memberBitmap;

    Test(Bitmap b)
    {
        memberBitmap = b;
    }
}
```

This far, I know memberBitmap is still a reference to originalBitmap. But what I would like to do is basically resize this Bitmap using:

```
memberBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(memberBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, filter);
```

Have I now stored a new Bitmap to the memory or have I changed the originalBitmap?

If it's so that I have created a new Bitmap, would there be any alteration to make it update the originalBitmap instead?

Like:

```
memberBitmap.createScaledBitmap(memberBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

By the sound of that API, it's probably creating a new bitmap in memory. You can check this by printing out the `toString()` on both objects after your constructor runs and see if their memory locations are the same.

For the second question: change the `originalBitmap` to reference to the new `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually creating a new Bitmap. In this case, it will create a new Bitmap and you lose the reference to the old one. If you did the code like so:

```
memberBitmap = b;
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(memberBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, filter);
```

You'll see that `memberBitmap` remains unchanged and `scaledBitmap` is a larger or smaller version.  However, one exception is if there is no scaling to be done at all in which case it simply returns the reference to `memberBitmap` and you'll have two references to the same object.

One way you can remove work is to create the Bitmap smaller in the first place using the `BitmapFactory.Options` parameters.  For example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, bitmapID);
```

This will create a Bitmap that's half the size (width and height) of the original image.  Unfortunately, this is very limiting and the value of `inSampleSize` must be in powers of 2.